# Check List Author

Tags: 2013, list, exception

I need to check the `Author` of a list, doesn't matter if `GenericList` or `DocumentLibrary`. I know there is the field `list.Author`, but for some lists an `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: User cannot be found.` is thrown.
A dirty solution would be to wrap it in a try-catch block...is there a nicer way?

```
using (var site = new SPSite("MyUrl"))
{
    var web = site.OpenWeb();
    var list = web.Lists[Guid.Parse("7A680350-F081-42B2-B5D6-7D28XXXXXXXX")];
    Console.WriteLine(list.Author);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: I updated my question adding the code

Comment: It does seems to be the issue pointed out by @Eric. If for some Lists you are getting this error then, first check and confirm if those users are not disabled in AD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is throwing a user cannot be found error, then the user who created the list or library is disabled and or removed from the environment. You'll have to try catch it and if it throws that error, substitute it with a generic account, a service account, or some text value depending on your needs.

This was a large problem for us while using the Metalogix migration tool to migrate to SharePoint Online. If the list creator was disabled in AD, you could not migrate the list.

Comment: Is there a way to identify if a list has been created by a user or by the `system`? E.g. `WebsiteObjects` has not been created by the user, but by the system once a `Website` has been created. Do you get the point?

Comment: it would be stamped with whoever did it, you'd have to look at the account to determine that afaik

Comment: Regarding `substitute it with a generic account, a service account, or some text value depending on your needs`...isn't the field readonly?

Comment: I had to update the field using an `UPDATE` statement on the db... 365 Lists updated. I hope SharePoint will not complain for some reason.

Comment: That is really not a good idea, you've potentially put your entire farm at risk and out of support. direct database writes are not supported by microsoft.

Comment: Yes I know, but there is no other way to change the `Author` of these lists